# How to use @solana/spl-token in vanilla JS after importing in HTML using CDN?

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-cli

I am trying to use @solana/spl-token(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token) npm module with the below react implementation and convert it to vanilla js accessing it via CDN(https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@solana/spl-token) link after importing in HTML.

**Unable to access the value of TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID in my vanilla JS code.**

React Library usage steps-

[image: Step 1]

Able to access here after a successful wallet connection

[image: Step 2]

---

Below is my HTML file-

[image: HTML File]

Vanilla JS File-
[image: JS File]

How can I access the TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID value here after a successful wallet connection?

Any help will be appreciated community.

Thanks